# Understanding of definition of ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

An *ordinal* is a well-ordered set $X$ such that for all $x\in X$, $(−∞, x) = x$.

How could the definition say $(−∞, x) = x$, how can we obtain this? I didn't understand. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this is saying is that each $x$ is precisely the set of all its predecessors in $X.$ In other words, letting $<$ be the order relation on $X$, for all $x\in X,$ we have $$x=\{t\in X:t<x\}.$$

The set-builder style set above is what the notation $(-\infty,x)$ means.

Comment: Okey. So, why not $\left( -\infty ,x\right]$?

Comment: The set $(-\infty,x]=\{t\in X:t\le x\},$ instead. This would be the set $x\cup\{x\},$ which is the immediate successor of $x$ in $X.$

Comment: Another way to think about this is as saying that $X$ is an ordinal if and only if it is well-ordered by $\in$--that is, for all $t,x,\in X,$ we have $t<x$ if and only if $t\in x.$

Comment: that is, is this $x=\left( -\infty ,x\right]$
false?

Comment: Yes. It is false to say that $x=(-\infty,x].$

Comment: Specifically, it is false because well-orders are irreflexive.

Comment: @CameronBuie I think you mean "$X$ is an ordinal if and only if it is **transitive and** well-ordered by $\in$";  every one-element set is well-ordered by $\in,$ likewise every set of ordinals, etc.

Comment: @bof: Right you are.

Answer (score 0):

That notation means x is the set of all sets less than x (in the well-order). There is no actual -infinity, it is just used as part of the interval notation colorfully.